# Can a satellite remain directly over a city?

Tags: orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics, satellites

Is it possible to put an artificial satellite into an orbit in such a way that it will always remain direct over a city (I mean at any specific place)?

Comment: [Yes.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geostationary_orbit)

Comment: thanks...... any example?
UPDATE: just checked your link. thanks

Comment: ....the "practical uses" section of the link ACuriousMind gives shows a few examples. However, a larger list [can be found at this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_satellites_in_geosynchronous_orbit).

Comment: thanks all... i have found my answer.... also please tell me why people always give negative rating to my question. after all, stackexchange is website for solving home work problems

Comment: No, Physics.StackExchange is *not* a homework help site. Please [see this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/). People probably gave this a downvote because you could have easily found this information by using [Google](http://www.google.com).

Comment: No.  See the answer of @DirkBruere

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is "No" - unless the city is on the equator. You specified "...it will always remain direct over a city". Satellites in geosync orbit might be visible to cities but not be directly overhead unless they are located on the equator.