# Can a satellite be put into orbit such that it will always remain directly over a city?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics, satellites

Isn't it possible if we just set it high enough so that it's angular speed matches with the earth's? 
I think that the city must be on the equator to make this happen. Am I correct?
Please can anyone show me mathematically?

Comment: Similar (if poorly titled) http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/148821/

Comment: All orbits must be in a plane that includes the center of the earth.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Can a satellite remain directly over a city](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/148821/)

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geosynchronous_satellite  and  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geostationary_orbit . the latter link shows that this can happen if the city is in the equator. otherwise there is an angle.